# What's the proper etiquette for "bumping" a question after a few days?

Tags: support, etiquette

What's the SE etiquette for bumping an answer after a couple days? Most people I know only go through the first few pages, so once your question gets a couple days old it may not be seen by the majority of users.

In my modding forums, it's acceptable to post a reply that bumps the topic back to the top of the listing, but somehow I didn't think it worked that way here with answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way is to use the bounty system if the question is two days old. An alternative is to edit the question and add more details too it, and you'll have a higher chance of getting an answer. The start page is listing posts descending on questions, answers and edits - meaning an edit will put your question to the top again.

But be careful, after five edits by you - the question is automatically transformed into a community wiki. Be sure to make valid edits only.

Good Luck!